# Почему ajax возвращает скобки?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

server

```
<?php
 $str = "string";
 $decode = json_encode($str);
  echo $decode;
?>
```

client

```
$.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      dataType:'text',
      url:"server.php",
      success:function(data){
        console.log(data); // будет "string"
        if(data == 'string') //не срабативает
      {
        $('a').text(data);
      }
      }});
```

Answer (score 0):

server

```
<?php
 $str = ["string"];
 $encode= json_encode($str);
  echo $encode;
?>
```

client

```
$.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      dataType:'json',
      url:"server.php",
      success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
        if(data[0] == 'string') 
      {
        $('a').text(data[0]);
      }
      }});
```